# Could we have question warnings on Web Applications?

Tags: support, tag-warnings

There are red and yellow warnings (tag tips?) shown when asking a question that match some regular expressions or meet other criteria like having a too short title (less than 15 chars) or when trying to use a "prohibited" tag like [untagged](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged).

Could we have this on Web Applications? If so, how should we suggest/request them?

I imagining ourselves discussing proposals about how to use this warnings on

tags

- [javascript](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript)
- [website](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website)

question title phrases like

- best way
- best to use
- looking for
- help with
- is there a way to
- is it possible to
- ...

Question body phrases like

- How to design
- develop an app
- ...

Related Q&A

- Stack Overflow

  - [Help the help-less with how-to-ask tag tips](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274632/1595451)
  - [Can the tag tips be in a non-critical color?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274897/1595451)

Stack Exchange Meta

- [What's the protocol for requesting a tag warning?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298887/289691)

Comment: The Community User bumped this question. Let's clean up the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tl;Dr: Yes, we can.

From [Taryn's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298890/289691) to [What's the protocol for requesting a tag warning?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298887/289691)

> Start with a post on the site's meta. This lets the community weigh in on the request, and also gives a paper trail in the event it is implemented. Figure out both whether this is needed and work on drafting the text for the warning so the CMs have some context and know what wording you think would be good.
>
> Once the community has voted on the post and there is a consensus that it should be done, then you'd need a member of SE Staff to take the next steps.
>
> A site mod should add the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag to the question, which will bring it to the CMs' attention and be added to their backlog through the [staff escalation process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348642/what-posts-should-be-escalated-to-staff-using-status-review-and-how-do-i-esca). If it's been a while since you heard anything, try pinging a Community Manager in chat like a mod-only chat room asking to take a look at the request.
>
> CM escalations are for issues about specific users, so that's not a great option here.