# Tag warning for [wordpress]

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tag-warnings

Tl;Dr: Please add the following tag warning to [wordpress](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress):

> Questions about WordPress (WP or wordpress.org), the open-source content management system, are off-topic in Web Applications SE. Check out [WordPress Development SE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) instead. If you are unsure about where to ask a question, you can ask for a site recommendation on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com).

---

[wordpress](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) is a tag from the early days of Web Applications. This tag it's a magnet of off-topic / neglected questions but also is a tag from incomming migrated questions from sites like Super User. Unfortunately most of the questions with this tag have being deleted.

The tag warning will help to those users that pay attention to the guidance from Ask question form. Users blatantly ignoring the form help, tag excerpt and tag warning will still facing that the questions might be eventually deleted by the Community user due to inactivey while the community participation doens't improve.

**Statistics**

In Web Applications SE there are 77 % (391 / 511 )  deleted questions with `[wordpress]`.

Percentage of deleted questions tagged `[wordpress]` in Web Applications SE.

[image]

All the questions from 2021 were deleted.

All the questions from 2022 so far are in danger of being automatically deleted by Community user (aka Roomba).

## Related

- [What should we do with WordPress questions and how tag them?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/162/88163)
- [Could we have question warnings on Web Applications?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4535/88163)

---

## Addendum

Remember that we have [wordpress.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress.com) for basic questions about creating and using a blog publish app at https://wordpress.com.

Questions about using web browsers to create and manage blogs and sites using web apps like WordPress, Wix, Blogger, Google Sites, Google Apps Script, and GitHub Pages might be on-topic if these questions aren't about installing software, handling advanced topics like Internet protocols, certificates, domain name servers (DNS records) because those tasks are done through another type of apps, not [application apps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_software). They are better suited for different types of people, not by [end-users](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_user). They could be better handled in  DevOps, Server Fault, Sharepoint SE, Webmasters, Worpress Development, and possibly others.

Comment: As explained in these MSE posts, “[Rules which \[…\] moderators need to follow regarding adding \[status-review\] tag in conflict of interest cases](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375604/162827)” and “[What posts should be escalated to staff using \[status-review\], and how do I escalate them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/162827)”, the [status-review] tag should only be used when there is a clear consensus from the community on a proposal and when there is no conflict of interest involved. This means that one should not add the [status-review] tag to their own posts.

Comment: However, you have added the [status-review] tag to a post that you have authored yourself, which is a conflict of interest. Moreover, your post has a score of zero, which indicates that there is no community support for your proposal. Therefore, I suggest that you remove the [status-review] tag from your post or explain why you think it is appropriate to use it in this case.

Comment: Since there is no consensus on this request, I will mark it as status-declined. Feel free to pose a new question here when there is sufficient community interest.

Comment: @SpencerG Thank you.

Comment: I would guess that the graph comes from some SEDE query [similar to this one](https://data.stackexchange.com/webapps/query/1662286/percentage-of-deleted-questions-in-given-tag-per-year?tagname=wordpress#graph).
(I guess it might be useful to include a link - so that other users can see what the query does, they can check for updates and possibly modify the query.)

Answer (score 0):

The CM Team is reviewing this question. The last Tuesday, SpencerG who is handling the current review stage, posted [a message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64589698#64589698) on [Google Fu](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7/google-fu), the Web Applications SE main chatroom.

> Hey just wanted to drop by as I am working on this request. It only got 2 votes and is thus at a deadlock would prefer a bit more engagement on it before I decided to decline or submit the request to devs.

Remember that the post timeline has a view to show the voting daily summaries. Since Tuesday, the question has gotten only one vote.

Related

- [Add a link to the timeline of a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126447/289691)